# Creating one surface skin without hidden parts from all these loose parts

Tags: faces, geometry

[image: y axis view]I have this file
https://uploadnow.io/f/mLKhQKj
and I want to keep only what is in front like a skin or so. As you can see the column is full. I press Z and the model turn with that face up. So, is there a way to combine all elements in one single face/mesh/skin and all elements that are in the back like  unseen half of the column and apples to be deleted ?[image: front]

[image: back]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- apply all modifiers by selecting everything "ctrl+a > visual geometry to mesh" and join everything with "ctrl+j"

[image]

[image]

2- draw a plane on top of your model

[image]

3- add desire amount of subdivision on plane set mode to simple and apply subdivision modifier

[image]

4- add "shrinkwrap" modifier on plane set method to project check positive and negative set target to your model

[image]

5- apply everything and hide or delete your original model.

[image]

6- if your problem have solved accept this answer and like it

also you can describe more about your case maybe someone can explain better like what you wanted to do with this model next .

Comment: I tried to follow your explanation but is not very clear (when is in object mode or edit mode) Anyway not working. Nothing happened . I am not very advanced on blender...

Comment: @IonApostol I have updated the answer with GIF's (animated images) , i hope you'd be able to use this method , if you wasn't get it completely i advise you to not to use blender at all since before you learn it

Comment: It works like a charm !! Thank you !

Comment: additionally you can use sculpt mode smooth brush to further smooth the things out

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if there is a UI command for that, but you could run a little script to delete all faces not pointing into the positive z-halfspace. Open the `Scripting` tab, create a new python text file and paste this script:

```
import bpy, bmesh

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
for face in mesh.faces:
    face.select = face.normal.z < 0

bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Select your object `panno_1000128_pesn` and run the script. All faces pointing downwards are deleted. If you also dont want to keep straight vertical faces, you can replace `<` with `<=`.

**Edit:** before running the script, you should also recalculate the normals of your model, its a bit messed up. Go in face edit mode, select all faces and do `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside`.

Comment: This will delete all model ! Not working .

Comment: @IonApostol i updated the script, please try again.

Comment: Did you tried with the file I provided ? It worked somehow but not very good. Big holes in my model and did not remove all faces/construction/model behind the front face. Maybe I am not very clear with what I want. I will put another image...

Comment: Maybe I am not very clear with what I want. I will put another image... First image is my model viewed from y axis. As you can see the column is hollow like a real column and what I want is to delete all parts of model that are not seen from z axis. I will use this model for cnc carving and I want just what is in front (z axis).

Comment: Yes i tried my script on your model, it removes all faces pointing down. But now i got what you mean. Creating one surface skin without hidden parts from all these loose parts is a different beast, @hamed.design 's answer is better suited for that.